# Take x% from an image

Tags: image, matrix

I was wondering for a good and easy way to get for example 5% of pixels of an Image (bitmap image) randomly and save them in another bitmap image or in array or whatever.

Is there such a way in C# or I should try to loop through the image and randomly select 5% of the data in an array[][].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I did it by my own method. I looped through the pixels of the image with randomly generated x and y coordinates and I selected x% of the all number of pixels from the original image. These pixels I copied to another bitmap image.